# Sample Size and Convergence of Sample Mean (Skewed Distribution)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sample-size, convergence, mean

I have data about the total revenue that a customer has spent with an app over their time since they installed the app, let's call this App1. The data looks like this:

```
    userid revenue
 1:   1556    6.12
 2:    379    6.13
 3:   1668   18.28
 4:   4206    6.09
 5:   3506   18.27
 6:   1601   41.18
 7:   2712   22.83
 8:    817    6.09
 9:   1311   24.33
10:   1711   98.62
11:   4858    6.08
12:   4585   12.16
13:   1326   34.17
14:    840    6.08
15:   1949    6.09
16:    693   11.43
17:   1760    6.09
18:   1926    6.05
19:   3508    0.00
20:   4867    0.00
```

So for example userid 1156 has spend \$6.12 to date while user 4867 has spent \$0.0 to date (or has not turned into a monetized user). The size of data for App1 is 5415 with 136 values strictly greater than zero.

The historgram of the revenue data looks like this:
[image]

The mean and standard deviation of this data are \$0.841446 and \$8.869, respectively.

I created a sampling distribution of the mean for this data:
[image]

The mean for the sampling distribution is \$0.8418324.

I have reason to believe based off of similar apps that the mean of the sampling distribution above will converge to a different mean of about \$1.00. What I am trying to do is determine the sample size I would need in order to see this become more probable. Here is the data of App2.

[image]

The mean and standard deviation of the above distribution are \$1.003136 and \$14.19739, respectively. The size of data for App2 is 31852 with 1075 elements strictly greater than zero. The sampling distribution for the mean of App2 looks like this:

[image]

and the two sampling distributions on the same plot: 
[image]

Here are my questions as well as some work that I have put into it:

I read an article here -https://www.isixsigma.com/tools-templates/sampling-data/how-determine-sample-size-determining-sample-size/- that determines how to find the sample size needed with a specified margin of error as well as a standard deviation possible from a prior experiment (In my case App2):

$$n = (\dfrac{Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sigma}{E})^2$$
where $E$ is the margin of error.

I calculate a 80% confidence level, $Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} = 1.282$, using the standard deviation from App2, $sd = \$14.19739$ with a margin of error $E = 0.20$ and I obtain

$$n = (\dfrac{1.282*14.19739}{0.20})^2 \approx 8281.956$$

So I determine my sample size as approximately 8300 users. So my questions here are:

1. Can I use the formula above to estimate the sample size? Or does using the formula above assume the distribution is normal?
2. If this is not correct then what would be the correct way to determine this?

I also used a power analysis, provided by this article - http://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/MPH-Modules/BS/BS704_Power/BS704_Power_print.html - following example 7, in particular.

Again, my goal is to determine the minimum sample size I would need to see the distribution with mean \$0.84 converge towards \$1.00.

I determined my effect size as:
$$ES = \dfrac{|\mu_0 - \mu_1|}{\sigma}$$

where $\mu_0 = 1.00$ and $\mu_1 = 0.84$ and $\sigma = 14.19$ and I estimate $n$ with an 80% power and 80% confidence interval

$$n = (\dfrac{1.96+0.84}{0.01139429})^2 \approx 34682.98.$$

This is a much larger sample size than the one estimated above.

My question for the power analysis is:

1. Is this also a correct way of determining the sample size for my given distribution (Skewed distribution)?

I realize this is a long post but any help would be greatly appreciated!

**NOTE:** Here are the distributions with zeros removed. 
[image]
[image]